# Variable nonvisibility in classes which extend another

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

I have a couple of classes: `book` and `video`, both of which `extend item`:

```
class item {
    int item_num;
    String title;
}
class video extends item {
    double length;
    char rating;
}
class book extends item {
    String author;
    int year;
}
```

I have a text file of values which need to be inserted into a list of `item`s. The text file looks like:

```
v    382    Armageddon    120    P
v    281    Scream    138    R
b    389    Othello    Shakespeare    1603
v    101    Cellular    110    P
b    482    Hatchet    Paulson    1987
```

And how the file is read:

```
list<item> theList;
item newItem;
while(true) {
    if(file.isEOF) { break; }
    if(file.getChar == 'v') {
        newItem = new video();
        /* the get___ methods below grab the next value
         * in the file. Values tab delimited */
        newItem.item_num = file.getInt();
        newItem.title = file.getString();
        newItem.length = file.getDouble();
        newItem.rating = file.getChar();
    } else if (file.getChar == 'b') {
        newItem = new book();
        newItem.item_num = file.getInt();
        newItem.title = file.getString();
        newItem.author = file.getString();
        newItem.year = file.getInt();
    }
    theList.add(newItem);
}
```

Netbeans pops an error that the `book` and `video` variables are not in class `item`.

Why is there nonvisibility for the variables in the classes which extend item? How do I access these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent class has no way of knowing what its child's fields are.  To gain proper access to those fields, instead of instantiating `item`, you'd instantiate `video` and `book` respectively, then add each of those to the list.  This also means that you can't have the `add` method at the end of both `if` statements, since they need to be added inside of the `if`s instead.

Since it'd be a mixed hierarchy collection, you could write `List<? super item> theList = new ArrayList<>();`  and add elements in that way.

Comment: A common example I've come across on polymorphism is an `animal` class which `dog`, `cat`, etc extend. These instantiate `dog` and `cat` like `animal var = new dog()`. What I'm doing is no different, no?

Comment: @gator:  You're trying to access the properties of a child object on its parent.  It's like trying to call the properties of a `String` on an `Object`; just because a `video` **is-an** `item`, that doesn't mean that an `item` **is-a** `book`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `newItem` is of type `item`. While a `book` and a `video` are both an `item` the reverse is not true.

If you want the compiler to see the variables declared in the subclasses you need to cast `newItem` to the appropriate subclass before accessing their variables. This can be done each time you need to but preferably you need to say `book b = new book()` instead of `item newItem = new book()`.